# Начиная &, кончая &

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Есть ли грамматическая ошибка?

> Он узнал все, **начиная причиной поступка, кончая именем хитреца**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: Он узнал всё, **начиная  с (от) причины поступка и кончая именем хитреца.**

Из словаря

**Начиная с кого-чего, в зн. предлога.**  Включая кого-, что-л.; в том числе и... Расселись все, начиная с гостей и кончая хозяевами. **Начиная от кого-чего, в зн. предлога.** Включая кого-, что-л., в том числе и... Наконец, все подружились, начиная от старожилов и кончая новичками.

Answer (score 2):

Есть. Падеж слова "причина" здесь не подходит для обозначения *начала* условного диапазона сущностей: здесь требуется "**начиная с причины**". Трудно даже подобрать естественный контекст, в котором бы что-то делали **"начиная чем-то"**. Проще придумать что-то фантастическое:

> Процесс взбивания кондитерской массы он осуществлял, несколько раз
>   заново **начиная** его длинной **мешалкой** из кристаллического сахара и
>   заканчивая уже её верхней, ещё не растворившейся в массе частью.

Comment: http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E0%F7%E8%ED%E0%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%26&gramm2=ins&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Comment: Вот аккурат, как у меня: http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E0%F7%E8%ED%E0%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%26&gramm2=ins&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%EA%EE%ED%F7%E0%FF&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=

Comment: А вот с союзом: https://goo.gl/j5KqLA